# Missing PostgreSQL package for Debian 8.x

Tags: postgresql, debian

Over several years and versions Debian offered a package for Postgresql, albeit not the latest versions which were only available via pinning to testing or unstable. 
But currently - march 2017 - the package search:
https://www.debian.org/distrib/packages#search_packages
does not yield any package for 'postgresql' in 'stable'=jessie, not even for debian 'testing'.
Only in 'unstable' postgresql is offered (9.6). 
What might be the technical background of this decision?
Can we expect to get full PostgreSQL support back in Debian?

Comment: Why don't you simply add the Postgres repositories: https://www.postgresql.org/download/linux/debian/

Comment: @Horse-with-no-name - this is one of many solutions to get PG running on jessie, but not my question.

Comment: For a different answer you will need to contact the maintainers of Debian directly.

Comment: I asked for the technical background. Maybe there is one.

Comment: As I said: this can only be answered by the Debian package maintainers. Stackoverflow is not the right place to ask this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic mentions a "practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development", and a respective answer could be "postgres needs glibc 42.31 or greater and debian 8 only supports 41.xx". BTW, the other 518 stackoverflow questions about debian packages do often just that. ...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this needs to be directed to the maintainers of the package, not SO.

Answer (score 0):

> the package search:
>   https://www.debian.org/distrib/packages#search_packages does not yield
>   any package for 'postgresql' in 'stable'=jessie,

Yes it does.

This search :

https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=postgresql&searchon=names&suite=stable&section=all

leads to this as an exact match

https://packages.debian.org/jessie/postgresql

> Package: postgresql (9.4+165+deb8u2) object-relational SQL database
>   (supported version)

Comment: Correct, it didn't yield the same result 2 days ago. 
Maybe I made a mistake in the query.